# NoReverseMatch error when using reverse function

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to redirect from one view to another and I get the following error:

> NoReverseMatch at /challenges/1/answer/
> Reverse for 'results' with arguments '(1,'test')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['challenges\/(?P<challenge_id>[0-9]+)\/results\/$']

I have the following code in views.py:

```
def results(request, challenge_id, result):
    ...

def answer(request, challenge_id):
    challenge = ...
    result = "test"
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('challenges:results', args=(challenge.id, result)))
```

Here's urls.py

```
path('<int:challenge_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
path('<int:challenge_id>/results/',views.results, name='results'),
path('<int:challenge_id>/answer/',views.answer, name='answer'),
```

My understanding is that 'reverse' in an HttpResponseRedirect would redirect to the 'results' page if I pass the 'result' in args?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your `urls.py` you have only one argument for `challanges:results`, but you are providing two arguments `(challange.id, result)`. Remove the `result` argument and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your `urls.py`, your *views* will look like this:

```
# Your results only expect `challenge_id` from url, so remove your result argument
def results(request, challenge_id):  
    ...

def answer(request, challenge_id):
    challenge = ...
    result = "test"

    # As your results url does not have result argument, remove the result argument
    # Now, your reverse will match the url and will work as expected
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('challenges:results', args=(challenge.id)))
```

Or

If you want to pass result to the results, then you have to change your urls to expect `result` as you did for `challenge_id`:

*urls*

```
path('<int:challenge_id>/results/<str:result>/',views.results, name='results'),
```

*views*

```
def results(request, challenge_id, result):
    ...

def answer(request, challenge_id):
    challenge = ...
    result = "test"
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('challenges:results', args=(challenge.id, result)))
```